# Has anyone migrated production machines from MySQL to MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, migration, mariadb

I'm running MySQL for most of our DBs right now, and would like to get off the Oracle ship before it takes more of a turn. My understanding is that the transition from MySQL->MariaDB should be trivial, but going the other way is not so easy. Has anyone made this jump yet?

Edit: Bonus points if you have anecdotal information on doing this with Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Before it takes more of a turn... to what?

Comment: I'm a FOSS guy, so the short answer is more closed and less community-supportive. I will restrain the more detailed/soap-boxy explanations for rant blogs and the like. =)

Comment: What app is running over top the db?  Is it supported?  Seems to me Even if it works today, the longer term question is whether the app will continue to work should mariaDB & MySQL diverge.

Comment: why not just go to the oss-forked mysql? Or have you perhaps considered PostgreSQL?

Comment: MariaDB isn't the only other option. There is also Percona Server.

Comment: In case anyone wants to know, we did end up deploying Percona.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have migrated various servers from MySQL to MariaDB a few weeks ago without any problem.

If you want the full list of what might not be compatible, you can have a look here: http://kb.askmonty.org/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility.

If you're upgrading to a higher version of MariaDB than MySQL was, you just have to jsut the mysql_upgrade binary as stated on http://kb.askmonty.org/en/upgrading-to-mariadb-from-mysql.

Moreover, with MariaDB 5.3 (released at the end of July), they now provide a proper repository, so there's no need to install by hand : http://downloads.askmonty.org/mariadb/repositories/

Comment: Does PHPmyadmin works fully with mariadb?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, the protocol is just the same as MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a friend who moved his vBulletin forum to MariaDB using the XtraDB engine without problems and noted some performance improvements compared to MySQL with InnoDB.

One of the things to take note of is that NDB does not work on MariaDB[[Source](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/ndb-disabled-in-mariadb)].

Comment: The performance gains could be just from switching to XtraDB, which can be used with MySQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

After reading http://vbtechsupport.com/606/, I migrated most of my servers over to MariaDB 5.2 builds and alot of clients have done the same with positive gains. Definitely worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Same here - migrated our only MySQL database to MariaDB two years ago. It was as easy as removing MySQL server package and installing MariaDB instead.